# Maven doesn't find an existing remote artifact

Tags: maven

I'm trying to use docker-compose-rule to run docker-compose files in junit integration tests.

I use the following dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.palantir.docker.compose</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-compose-rule-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.32.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.palantir.docker.compose/docker-compose-rule-junit4 -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.palantir.docker.compose</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-compose-rule-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>0.32.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but for some reason the artifact is not found by maven (for none of the available versions).

As far as I can say, the artifact is found in the jcenter as shows in [bintray](https://bintray.com/palantir/releases/docker-compose-rule).
It also exists on [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.palantir.docker.compose/docker-compose-rule-junit4/0.32.0).

Can someone please tell why can't I use these libraries?

Alternatively, can I reference maven to take the library from a specific url with a specific jar file, for example from [github](https://github.com/palantir/docker-compose-rule), or from [here](https://palantir.bintray.com/releases/com/palantir/docker/compose/docker-compose-rule-core/0.32.1/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.palantir.docker.compose/docker-compose-rule-core/0.32.0), the jar you are looking for is not in the maven default `Central` repository, but is in the `Palantir` repository. You can add

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Palantir</id>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/palantir/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

into your pom.xml, and try again.